# mails are going into spam folder while sending

Tags: asp.net, email, email-spam

My site is hosted on a shared hosting server.

I am sending email's from my website.And below is the SMTP details that i am using :-

SMTP SERVER NAME :   relay-hosting.secureserver.net

POST :   25

From Email ID :  xyz@mydomainname.com

And the problem is when we send email's to any gmail or hotmail email id's then the mails are going into Spam/Junk folder.But not for Yahoo email id(means mails are goin in Inbox directly while using any Yahoo email id or any email id).

> > And i think it's because Gmail and Hotmail are not considering above SMTP details secure.That's why mails are going into Inbox(for Gmail/Hotmail).
> >
> > Can any one knows how can we fix this issue.

FYI,I am working with ASP.NET 4.0

Comment: Are you sending html email or plain text? Cos HTML Emails find their way into the spam folders unless well developed.

Answer (score 0):

Mail providers like Gmail and Outlook.com (formerly known as Hotmail) will most likely use [Sender Policy Framework (SPF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and [DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM)](http://www.dkim.org/) to determine if a message is spam by ensuring that the sender is the legitimate owner of the domain name used to send from. Exactly how Gmail and Outlook.com filters spam is not well known but setting up either SPF or DKIM or both should help to avoid getting your mail flagged.

To ensure that your mail is not flagged as spam you will have to configure your DNS records to provide correct SPF and DKIM information.

Online you can get a report on your mail. [Port 25 has an email verification service](http://www.port25.com/support/authentication-center/email-verification/) that you can use.

Comment: Leversage thanks for your answer.That is very helpful information.

But can you assist me on setting the SPF or DKIM ? How can i set those parameters on Godaddy ?

Comment: @Pawan: There are many tutorials and discussions on the internet about how to setup SPF and DKIM.